# How do I get my stock ringtones back?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, ringtone

I have a Droid X, and I've been having issues with my music lately.  I finally deleted the Albums, Music, and Playlists directories from my SD Card, and used SDRescan to get the media library to update.  That did the trick for the music, but now my stock ringtones have disappeared.  Were they on the SD card?

Why did they disappear, and how can I get them back?  My phone isn't rooted.

Comment: I realize this isn't very helpful, but http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4908 describes a possibly-similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I tried rebooting when I was seeing the problem, and that didn't help.  I wound up setting two songs from my SD card as the ringtone and notification sounds, and that didn't help either.  My phone crashed hard today while downloading an app, and I had to pull the battery to restart it.  After that, the original choices reappeared.  Go figure.